# Parsing specific fields and counting the occurrence with python

Tags: python, file, parsing, python-2.6

I have a file separated by delimiter '|'  like this:

```
age=None|sex=M|DEPT=ID1|YEAR=1995|
age=10|sex=M|DEPT=None|YEAR=1992|
age=None|sex=None|DEPT=ID1|YEAR=1991|
age=20|sex=F|DEPT=ID2|YEAR=1990|
age=20|sex=M|DEPT=ID3|YEAR=1991|
```

In python, how do I get the output of how many times each field is repeated. 
Do we have any built-in functions? I looked into collections.update() but my environment
uses  python-2.6.  Unfortunately I can't use that option(and won't be able to copy 
new module files into that environment manually too).

Thanks for any help or pointers.

example output:

```
1 times Sex=F
3 times Sex=M

1 times age=10
2 times age=None
2 times age=20

2 times YEAR=1991 
...

2 times DEPT=ID1
```

etc

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you looking for here? Help parsing the file or a fast way to count/sort the data?

Comment: Helping in paring file with this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

import csv

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = defaultdict(int)
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|"):
        for field in row:
            answer[field] += 1

for k in sorted(answer, key=lambda k: answer[k]):
    print answer[k], "times", k
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter

import csv
import itertools

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|")))
for k in sorted(answer, key=lambda k:answer[k]):
    print answer[k], "times", k
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get this error message when checking above code. ""AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute '__get__'   . system has python-2.6.1 . The second method says "ImportError: cannot import name Counter". I thinks its because of python-version.

Answer (score 1):

Use get in dictionary may help:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    dict = dict()
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split('|')
        for item in line:
            dict[item] = dict.get(item,0) + 1
for k in dict:
    print dict[k], 'times', k
```